# How to Recover PostgreSQL 8.0 Database

Tags: postgresql, recovery

On my PostgreSQL 8.0 database, I started receiving a "ERROR:  could not open relation 1663/17269/16691: No such file or directory" message, and now my data is inaccessible.
Any ideas on how to recover at least some of the data? Professional support is an option.

Regards.

RP

Comment: First step: immediately shut it down and take a filesystem-level copy of all postgresql-related directories.

Comment: Did that. Have the data folder offline.

Comment: Have you already tried copying the filesystem copy to another server and starting that cluster? Did it start?

Comment: I did, copied to a totally different server (both Windows). It started, but whenever I try to do anything, I just get that error message. Do you know of any professional support?

Comment: Start here: http://www.postgresql.org/support/professional_support/ - if you have a recent backup of your database that is probably the simplest/most cost effective solution though.

Comment: Thanks, I already did. Only two references to "disaster recovery" in the Europe section, though, and one's site is only in dutch. I don't mind paying, but I would like to try something else before that. By the way, no backup, unfortunately. I am now trying to use the pg_xlog.

Comment: pg_xlog will replay automatically on startup. Any of the mainstream support groups can help you - where in Europe are you?

Comment: Portugal. What mainstream support groups are you mentioning? Sorry for my ignorance... Where shall I ask for support, on the PostgreSQL mailing lists?

Comment: Sorry, no I meant the major companies. 2nd Quadrant have a man in Italy. Andreas Scherbaum is in Germany but you both speak English, so that's not necessarily a barrier. Likewise credativ. Over in the US there's Command Prompt and Enterprise DB. Can't say what they're like on price (professional IT consulting is not cheap I'm afraid), but they'll all know what they're doing. Others on the list might be equally good of course. Mailing list offers a very good level of support but might not turn things around by tomorrow lunchtime for you.

Comment: Please specify the **exact** Postgres version. There are four major releases in the 8.x line (with only one of them still being supported: 8.4)

Answer (score 2):

If you want your data back in a hurry and it's worth something to you, then the professional support option should be simple enough.

Some things to check, now that you've got a full backup of all your database (that's base, pg_clog, pg_xlog and all the other folders at that level).

1. Does that file actually exist? It might be a permissions problem rather than the file actualy going missing.
2. Check your anti-virus/security packages - have they mistakenly quarantined the file? If you can exclude PostgreSQL's database directories from scans/active scans that's worthwhile too.
3. Make a note of everything you can remember about when this happened and what happened just before. This will help with troubleshooting for you or a consultant.
4. Check the logs likewise - this error will be logged, find the first occurrence and see if there's anything odd before.
5. Double-check you really do have all your existing files backed up, and restart PostgreSQL.
6. Try connecting as user postgres to database postgres or database template1. If that works then the file is one of your database files rather than the global list of users or some such.
7. Try creating an empty file with the right name (and permissions - check the other files). If you are really lucky it's just an index. Otherwise it could be a data table you can live without. Then you can dump other tables individually.
8. OK - if you're here then you can connect to your DB. Those numbers in the file-path are PostgreSQL's OIDs identifying system objects. You can try a couple of useful queries here. These two queries should give you the IDs of the databases and then the object with the missing file. This is useful information for your professional too.

   SELECT oid, datname, dattablespace FROM pg_database;
   SELECT * FROM pg_class WHERE relfilenode = 16691;

Remember *make sure you have the filesystem backup before tinkering*.

Comment: Thanks, Richard!
Just some remarks: I don't know what happened, it could be a power failure. I can connect to both databases (template1 and the one that is corrupt). Nothing weird in the logs, what bugs me most is that none of the files/directories (1663/17269/16691) exists.
I will contact professional support.

Comment: They'll probably cry once they hear you are on 8.0 - that was released in 2005! I'm surprised the directories don't exist - particularly 1663 - that should be your database. I've edited the answer with some more trouble-shooting you can do.